# Javascript class, constructor and seed value

Tags: javascript

Help on below query would help me get going and clarify many doubts. So far, I read I could have class in JS through function statements, and JSON notation to hold object values. So, in the below code

1. how to write the testData variable which holds some shape values
2. how to initialize the Shape objects from testData. I may be able to create the object by assigning each member

   ```
   var obj = {
               x: testData[i].x,
                 y: testData[i].y,
               ...      
           };
   ```

is this the proper way, or can we use constructors as described [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html)

```
var testData = [ {}, {} ]


//Shape class

var Shape = function(x, y, w, h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.calculateArea = function() {
            alert("Area..");
};


func test() {
var arr = [];
for (var i=0,l=testData.length; i<l; i++) {
       var s = testData[i];
           var obj = // how to construct Shape object here  through constructor          
        };
arr.push(obj);

}
```

Comment: `JSON != object literals`. In your code there is no JSON at all.

Comment: Ya.. Alex mentioned below the same.. still getting familiar with a  language which is new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a new object (a `Shape`, in this case) with the `new` keyword. So you would use:

```
var obj = new Shape(testData[i].x, testData[i].y, testData[i].w, testData[i].h);
```

Comment: so no explicit declaration of constructor is needed? and do I need to specify all the parameters, or do they work in an overloaded fashion (say not specifying the function member or h parameter)?

Comment: In javascript, the `function` _is_ the constructor. Assuming you come from Java, javascript functions can't be overloaded. If you were to call `Shape(x, y, w)`, `h` would be `undefined`, but not throw an error. However, you can have conditional checks within the constructor to replicate the effects of overloading. [here is a great guide to javascript OOP](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need testData to be JSON for transport from a server etc.

```
testData = [{ x: 1, y: 1, w: 1, h: 1}, ...]
```

Then as @digitalFish suggests you can create the Shape objects from each test data element by

```
var obj = new Shape(s.x, s.y, s.w, s.h);
arr.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator allows you to instantiate the object via its constructor.

```
var circle = new Shape(x, y, width, height);
```

Also, it isn't called *JSON notation* (which would be JavaScript Object Notation Notation), it's called *object literal notation*.

Answer (score 0):

The new operator can cause problems in some edge cases when .apply is needed. I believe the best method is like below. This also is a little DRYer as you don't repeat 'this' throughout.

```
var createShape = function(x, y, w, h) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        w: w,
        h: h,
        calculateArea: function() {
            alert("Area..");
        }
    };
};
var a = createShape(1,2,3,4);
var b = createShape(4,3,2,1);
console.log(a, b);
```